# how can we join two different tables where no common column is present using pandas

Tags: python, mime-types, smtplib

I have two tables one with offerid and other with emailid .I want both to be merged and come in a table.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("offer1.txt")
data1 = pd.read_csv("offer2.txt")

print data.merge(data1, left_on='listid', right_on='profile/emailid', how='left')
```

I am getting output like this:

```
 listid                   profile/emailid
0    588001                            NaN

1    614001                            NaN

2       NaN                       rcruise295@yahoo.com

3       NaN                         2282377983
```

I want like this

```
 listid                   profile/emailid

  588001                 rcruise295@yahoo.com

  614001                   2282377983
```

can any on help me

Comment: Can you give a specific input / output example? How the merged dataframe should look?

Comment: inputs:
offer1.txt:

listid

588001 
614001

offer2.txt:

 profile/emailid

rcruise295@yahoo.com
2282377983

output needed:

 listid                   profile/emailid
 588001                 rcruise295@yahoo.com
 614001                   2282377983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output you specify, seems that you want to merge on index

```
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
data1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
data.merge(data1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Thankx a lot kosnik